# Session Tracking Login in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new using `spring mvc` in general. I'm generating login page and my problem is that it always redirects me to the `notLoggedIn` prompt after I've tried to log in.

#### The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method= RequestMethod.POST) //login 
public String logIn(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) {
    HttpSession session= request.getSession();

    request.getSession().setAttribute("isLoggedIn", "true");

    String uname=request.getParameter("userid");
    String pword=request.getParameter("password");
    boolean exists=logInService.checkLogIn(uname, pword);

    if(exists){
      session.setAttribute("userid", uname);
      return "Users"; //return to next success login jsp 
    } else {
        return "Interface2"; //return to Invalid username and password jsp
    }
}
```

#### The interceptor:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {
    HttpSession session= request.getSession();

    if(session.getAttribute("userid")!=null && session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn")!=null ){
        System.out.println("Logged In");
    }
    else{
  response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/modulename/notLoggedIn");
         System.out.println("Not logged in");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interceptor blocks every http request and does some check but it should actually allow and not check for **login** http request. Following changes are just to get the use case work. Refer note at the bottom for suggestions.

```
   @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws Exception {
    HttpSession session= request.getSession();

    if(session.getAttribute("userid")!=null && session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn")!=null ){
        //user has already logged in . so therefore can access any resource
        System.out.println("Logged In");
        return true;
    }

    //if code reaches here means that user is not logged in

    //allow login http request. modify checks accordingly. like you can put strict equals.
    if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login")){
        //user is not logged in but is trying to login. so allow only login requests
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //user is not logged in and is trying to access a resource. so redirect him to login page
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/modulename/notLoggedIn");
        System.out.println("Not logged in");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can reorder your login http request check to avoid login request for already logged in user.

Comment: i hope you understood my explanation. Can you accept and upvote if answer was good enough

Comment: I have another question, is there any other possible solution for that? Thank you :)

Comment: Also, can you please explain it more in detail? I don't quite understand. Thank you

Comment: I suggest you do case by case analysis. When user is not logged in but requesting some resource. When user is logged in and requesting a resource. Think how should execution happen step by step. You can use java debugging or put log statements and analyze. You ll much more this way. Let me know if you are facing any trouble

Comment: Umm hey, after some very minor revisions it went back to redirecting to the notLoggedIn prompt. Can you please help me with this. Thank you so much

Comment: What changes did you do?

Comment: ` if(session.getAttribute("userid")!=null && session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn")!=null ) ` from this I replaced it to ` if(request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/login") && session.getAttribute("isLoggedIn")!=null ) `

Comment: This is incorrect. This means that it is a login request and attribute is logged in is not null then it means user logged in. User logged in means tat just is logged in is not null . you don't have to check if it is login request. You need to check for login request only if user is not logged in. Here it would be like put an if below ur is logged in check. To be more explicit, remove your login request check and create a new if block below this if and place this login request check and in then block put return true as dis request does not login check becoz only dis request allows user to login

Comment: i have made some changes to the answer. let me know what changes were you trying to do